# Python package - setup __init__.py to import method direct from submodule

Tags: python, package, python-import

Let's say we have a Python Project like this:

```
setup.py
project/
    __init__.py
    subdir/
        __init__.py
        submodule.py
```

And in submodule.py looks like this:

```
def my_method():
   return "I am a method"
```

How can I setup the `__init__.py` (`project/__init__.py` and `subdir/__init__.py`) files that I can import the method "my_method" like this after I installed the package:

```
from project.subdir import my_method
```

**I do not want** to do something like this:

```
from project.subdir import submodule
submodule.my_method()
```

Any idea? :-)

Comment: you need to import `my_method` in `project/subdir/__init__.py`

Comment: I did it like you said, with a minimal example and I just do not get it to work.

`from package.subdir import my_method` does not work.

Comment: Okay - I am stupid. 
Your solution works 100% like I want. 

...I added `init.py` files... and not `__init__.py`. 

Thank you very much! :)